# C# Assign Variable to Constant

Tags: c#, variables, constants

I am trying to assign a variable to a constant. Yes I understand the fact and the theory that a constant should not be assigned a variable but here is the scenario...

I have created an assembly and I need to do version checking on the assembly as it could be plugged into various applications. I am writing and reading from XML files, and the version is detrimental as the assembly will evolve over time, and I don't want to hard code; somewhere along the line over time, someone WILL forget to do it. With this in mind, the XML could (will) change, and I do not want to overwrite previous XML versions, nor do I want to read from previous version XML files; previous version information must stay in tact; because an application could be upgraded at any time.

I retrieve the file version information;

```
private static readonly FileVersionInfo File_Version_Info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

When I write my XML, I include my own namespaces which must include the current version, but as I stated it will only accept a constant;

```
[DataContract(Name = "name", Namespace = "https://www.my_namespace/v" + **Need_To_Add_Version_As_String_Here**, IsReference = false)]
```

I cannot for instance, use;

```
File_Version_Info.FileMajorPart.ToString();
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mention constant in your question but you use a ```static readonly```, not a ```const``` could you change that?
I would suggest that you use a static with a private setter. This way you can set it after retrieving data, but you can keep it non-editable for the 'outside world'

Comment: @H.J.Meijer: I think OP's problem lies in the region of the Attribute, which are initialized by constants.

Comment: Isn't this one of the reasons why you shouldn't put versioning info into paths, namespaces and/or url's?

Comment: @Stefan: you are right, I cannot declare my File_Version_Info as static.

Comment: @Stefan on the contrary, versions *are* part of XML namespaces. A namespace URI is *not* the same as a REST API's URL anyway. Versioning an XML or even a JSON Schema though is very different from versioning an API. You can change an API's version all you want as long as the *schema* remains the same. Changing the schema though essentially changes the API

Comment: @Stefan: any reason why you say I shouldn't put versioning info into paths? I've seen this done plenty times. I am not arguing with what you are saying, I am merely wanting to understand.

Comment: @Bazïnga You wouldn't be happy at all if a SOAP service changed namespaces after every build, breaking your client code. A *namespace* is *not* a URL that you can change any time you want without forcing clients to recompile and redeploy. You should *not* change the schema version unless there's a *breaking change in the XSD itself*.

Comment: @Bazïnga: well, I was actually wondering myself. I know there are some guid lines regarding to put your versioning where. I meant path here in a broader sense than a file path. It seems that Panagiotis actually knows something about the subject :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the xml file does get sent to a web service. Will the version info in the namespace not decide if the packet should be accepted or rejected? Also, I could very easily set the version in the namespace by hard coding it, but if the schema changes, the next person will forget to update the hard coded version information and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: So, I'll up-vote since the question is actually broader than this specific use-case. Maybe you can reflect that in your question

Comment: @Bazïnga instead of avoiding, you *create* a versioning problem for your clients. *The client proxies* will need to be recompiled. You are mistaking schema versioning for API versioning. Again, think how your customers would react if you broke their automatically generated proxies *every time you deployed an internal, invisible fix*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks; I should rather have separate versioning "control" of my schema and API. When code changes are made my API version will change, but my schema won't, so the schema version shouldn't change as there really is no need for it; as you say, it would create unnecessary headaches on each compile. And visa versa; when my schema changes my API won't necessarily changes. I could much rather have a version tag inside the xml to indicates my API version. Thank you for making that clear, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Why am I getting down voted on this?